# How to get month in small letters using jdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

The query which i am using is

```
        String sql=select trim(CdateTo) cdate,
        count(case when Verified = 'WithGrant' then 1 end) as grant,
        count(case when Verified = 'WithDiscount' then 1 end) as CC
        from mse where Verified IN ('WithDiscount','WithGrant') and 
        CdateTo > SYSDATE - 9 
        GROUP BY trim(CdateTo) 
        ORDER BY TO_DATE(cdate,'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

and the spring jdbcTemplate code is like

```
        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<Trif>() {
                @Override
                public Trif mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    Trif trif = new Trif();
                    *************some code*******
                    Trif.setDate(rs.getString("cdate"));
                    ***********someCode*********
                    return trif;
                }
            });
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            return null;
        }
```

this return me date like 31-MAY-16
where i want it should return me like 31-May-16 where the month May is showing first letter in capital and others are in small
 how i can acheive this?

Comment: why don't you just manage a simple String operation? Here you are : 
String smallLetters = rs.getString("cdate"); etc. etc.

Comment: Just handle this on the Java side where the application can remain stateless and scale. SimpleDateFormat class can easily manage this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume the date is always formatted as DD-MONTH-YY this code should work for you:

```
    private String capitalizeMonth(String s) {
        char[] c = s.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        c[s.indexOf('-') + 1] = Character.toTitleCase(c[s.indexOf('-') + 1]);
        return new String(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As already advised, you can handle the case on Java side.
However, in your query there are some places to pay attention to.

you have

```
select trim(CdateTo) cdate,
```

that means you return a varchar which is fine as long as the CdateTo is varchar itself.
But

```
CdateTo > SYSDATE - 9
```

means that in one of those lines you have an implicit type conversion - and this depends on the NLS settings. Once the default settings change - your code might broke.

Now with the original question. Oracle has a really nice function, `INITCAP`, that does the thing you actually need. so doing something like 
`select initcap(trim(CdateTo)) cdate` might help.

However, if the type of your `CdateTo` column is `DATE`, then the correct way of dealing with the problem would be:

```
select trim(to_char(CdateTo,'dd-Mon-yy')) cdate,
```

Pay attention on the format mask and the capital M in `Mon` - this will make your result consistent and independent of changes in session/system settings

Comment: thanks man. I already handle this situation on Java side but I am looking for query solution. I also tried trim(to_char(CdateTo, 'dd-Mon-yy'))  but this query take a lot of time. Because I've huge data. Your explanation will help me though  :)